# Generating maximum number of 3-tuples from a list of 2-tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of 2-tuples and would like to generate as many 3-tuples as possible from that list. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import itertools
a = list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 2))
```

i.e.

```
a = [(1, 2), (1, 3), ..., (1, 9), (2, 3), ..., (8, 9)]
```

Now I would like to find the maximum amount of cyclic 3-tuples that can be generated from this list, one such 3-tuple would be:

```
(1,2),(2,3),(1,3) -> (1,2,3)
```

Each 2-tuple can only be used once. I suppose I could use a brute-force approach, but I have a feeling that it can be done in a much smarter way. Any thoughts?

For anyone interested, the problem is a scheduling problem. n teams should play each other once during a season. A season consists of a number of tournaments, ideally a tournament consists of 3 teams where all 3 teams play each other (3 games in total in such tournament). The goal is to avoid tournaments with only two teams.

Comment: Can you relate this to [Cycles in a graph](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/)?

Comment: I suppose, but if we think of this in terms of edges in an undirected graph, we are dealing with a complete graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph . We then would like to find as many 3-cycles as possible in this graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to use `itertools.permutations()` to generate cycles.

How big is your dataset. For small datasets you can simply brute force it with `itertools.product()`, e.g:

```
In [1]:
import itertools as it

a = list(it.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 2))
cycle = lambda x, y, z: x[1] == y[0] and y[1] == z[0] and z[1] == x[0]
[(x, y, z) for x, y, z in it.product(a, repeat=3) if cycle(x, y, z)]

Out[1]:
[((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 4), (4, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 5), (5, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 6), (6, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 7), (7, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 8), (8, 1)),
 ...]
```

So I now understand your problem, you can take a more constructive approach, e.g.:

```
In [2]:
from collections import deque

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]    
sched = [[x for x in zip(*[iter(a)]*3)]]
for i in range(3):
    r = []
    for i, x in enumerate(sched[-1]):
        x = deque(x)
        x.rotate(i)
        r.append(x)
    sched.append(list(zip(*r)))
sched

Out[2]:
[[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)],
 [(1, 6, 8), (2, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7)],
 [(1, 9, 5), (6, 2, 7), (8, 4, 3)],
 [(1, 7, 4), (9, 6, 3), (5, 2, 8)]]
```

Comment: Thanks, the size of the set is small (say less than 20 2-tuples), so brute-force will do. Curios though for an elegant algorithm

Comment: Each 2-tuple can only be used once ?

Comment: @B.M, that is correct. In the output (1,2) occurs several times which is not allowed. The output must be further filtered, but it is a start

Comment: @AChampion, excellent. I have not had the time to investigate your solution thoroughly, but at a first glance it looks spot on.