# Generating 3-tuples from a set of 2-tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

In an earlier question:

[Generating maximum number of 3-tuples from a list of 2-tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507127/generating-maximum-number-of-3-tuples-from-a-list-of-2-tuples)

I got an answer from @AChampion that seems to work if the number of 2-tuples is divisible by 3. However, the solution fails if we, for example, have 10 2-tuples. After fumbling with it for a while I'm under the impression that it is impossible to find a perfect solution for say:

```
(1,2)(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)
```

So I'm interested in finding one solution that minimizes the number of remainder tuples. In the example above the result could be:

```
(1,2,3)           # derived from (1,2), (1,3), (2,3)
(1,4),(2,4),(3,4) # remainder tuples
```

The rule for generating 3-tuple from 3 2-tuple is:

```
(a,b), (b,c), (c,a) -> (a, b, c)
```

i.e. the 2-tuples is a cycle with length 3. The order of the elements in a 3-tuple is not important, i.e:

```
(a,b,c) == (c,a,b)
```

I'm actually interested in the case where we have a number n:

```
for x in range(1,n+1):
    for y in range(1,n+1):
        if x!=y:
            a.append((x,y))

# a = [ (1,2),...,(1,n), (2,1),(2,3),...,(2,n),...(n,1),...,(n,n-1) ]
```

From a, minimize the number of 2-tuples that is left when producing 3-tuples. Each 2-tuple can only be used once.

I wrapped my brain around this for several hours but I can't seem to come up with an elegant solution (well, neither have I found an ugly one:-) for the general case. Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be clearer if you included the information under which conditions 3 2-tuples can be "converted" into a 3-tuple. So please include the relevant informations from the linked post.

Comment: Also is the order relevant in the 2 tuples? Is `(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)` identical to `(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 2)`? Essentially each tuple will be in there twice (normal + mirrored), is that correct?

Comment: I've added a bit more info, hope it helps to clarify the question

Comment: Sorry, missed your last question, yes, (x,y) belongs to the set of 2-tuples iff (y,x) belongs to the set as well

Comment: Looking at your previous question, are you looking to construct a [Steiner triple system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system)?

Comment: David, I will have to study this closer to figure out if its what Im looking for:-) Meanwhile you can think of it as a league with n teams where each team should play against every other team twice. The idéa is to gather 3 teams at a time so they can play each other once (each team plays 2 matches, i. e 3 matches per gathering)

Comment: For 9 teams there will be a total of 9*8 games. A perfect solution can be found using 24 gatherings

Comment: For 4 teams a perfect solution cant be found, there will be a remainder of 2 games

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, excellent information, thank you. In http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/sts.pdf it is stated (Theorem 1.1.3) A Steiner triple system of order v exists if and only if v ≡ 1 or 3 (mod 6). So v= 3,7,9,13,... will be fine. An interesting followup question that arises is whether we can take m instances of STS(v), where v is not in {1,3}mod 6, and form another set of triplets from the remainder 2-tuples.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to create number of combinations that will use for replacement. Then loop over you data for 3 item that contains any of above combinations and replace them.
I have done thi in several steps.

```
from itertools import combinations

# create replacements elements
number_combinations_raw = list(combinations(range(1, 5), 3))

# create proper number combinations
number_combinations = []
for item in number_combinations_raw:
    if (item[0] + 1 == item[1]) and (item[1] + 1 == item[2]):
        number_combinations.append(item)

# create test data
data = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

# reduce data
reduce_data = []
for number_set in number_combinations:
    count = 0
    merged_data = []
    for item in data:
        if (number_set[0] in item and number_set[1] in item) or (number_set[1] in item and number_set[2] in item) \
            or (number_set[0] in item and number_set[2] in item):
            merged_data.append(item)
            count += 1
    if count == 3:
        reduce_data.append((number_set, merged_data))

# delete merged elements from data list and add replacement
for item in data:
    for reduce_item in reduce_data:
        for element in reduce_item[1]:
            if element in data:
                data.remove(element)

        data = [reduce_item[0]] + data

# remove duplicated replaced elements
final_list = list(dict.fromkeys(data))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4)]
```

Comment: I think (3,4) is missing in your test data

Comment: After posting this, I learned that this is called an `partial Steiner triple system`.  https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235128/saulspatz posted a very nice explanation in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238655/repeated-incomplete-steiner-triplets?noredirect=1#comment6662100_3238655

Comment: I see now, that (3,4) is missing in my question as well, sorry about that